# Клик по блоку + клик по кнопке

Tags: javascript, html, css

Друзья, как сделать чтоб при клике на блок нажималась так же и кнопка, которая находится в этом блоке?

Прилагаю [пример](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/axdaGN). Есть блок, по клику на сам блок должен вылазить блок, а пока что работает если кликнуть на саму кнопку (три точки внизу).

```js
var show_filter_list = function(obj) {
  obj.classList.toggle("active");
  console.log(obj.nextElementSibling)


  panel = obj.nextElementSibling;
  panel.classList.toggle("opened");
}

var show_advances = function(obj) {
  obj.classList.toggle("active");

  panel = obj.previousElementSibling;
  panel.classList.toggle("opened");
}
```

```css
.credit {
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  max-width: 922px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: relative;
}

.credit-wrap {
  padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.credit:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.credit__title {
  color: #2c7bdd;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 38px;
}

.credit__num {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.credit__name {
  color: #9c9898;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.credit__more-btn {
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #0e86d6;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 0;
  transition: all .2s;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 10px 30px;
}

.credit__num--fw {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.credit-time,
.credit-pcent {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.credit-advances {
  margin-left: 40px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  border-top: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.credit-advances__list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.credit__list-item {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.credit-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  background: #ddd;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 45px;
  height: 12px;
  margin-left: -22.5px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background .2s;
}

.credit:hover .credit-toggle {
  background: #0e86d6;
}

.credit-toggle--circle {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  transition: background .2s;
}

.credit-toggle--circle:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -10px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  transition: background .2s;
}

.credit-toggle--circle:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -10px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  transition: background .2s;
}

.credit-advances {
  display: none;
}

.credit-advances.opened {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="credit">
  <div class="credit-wrap">
    <div class="credit__logo">
      <img src="img/credit-logo.png" alt="" width="112px">
    </div>
    <div class="credit__sum">
      <p class="credit__title">CreditStar</p>
      <p class="credit__num">30 000 ₽</p>
      <span class="credit__name">Сумма</span>
    </div>
    <div class="credit-time">
      <p class="credit__num">15 минут</p>
      <span class="credit__name">Время</span>
    </div>
    <div class="credit-pcent">
      <p class="credit__num credit__num--fw">1.5% в день</p>
      <span class="credit__name">Процент</span>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="credit__more-btn">Подробнее</a>
  </div>

  <div class="credit-advances">
    <ul class="credit-advances__list">
      <li class="credit__list-item">Сумма займа от 1 000 до 30 000 рублей</li>
      <li class="credit__list-item">Срок от 7 до 30 дней</li>
      <li class="credit__list-item">Процентная ставка 1.5% в день</li>
      <li class="credit__list-item">Выдача на банковкую карту</li>
      <li class="credit__list-item">Нужен только паспорт</li>
      <li class="credit__list-item">Гражданам РФ с 18 лет</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="credit-toggle" onclick="show_advances(this)">
    <div class="credit-toggle--circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Используйте для этого триггеры http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F

Answer (score 0):

`event.stopImmediatePropagation();`

```js
const creditToggle = document.querySelector('.credit-toggle');

var show_filter_list = function(obj) {
  obj.classList.toggle("active");
  console.log(obj.nextElementSibling)


  panel = obj.nextElementSibling;
  panel.classList.toggle("opened");
}

var show_advances = function() {
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  creditToggle.classList.toggle("active");

  panel = creditToggle.previousElementSibling;
  panel.classList.toggle("opened");
}
```

```css
.credit {
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  max-width: 922px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: relative;
}

.credit-wrap {
  padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.credit:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.credit__title {
  color: #2c7bdd;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 38px;
}

.credit__num {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.credit__name {
  color: #9c9898;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.credit__more-btn {
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #0e86d6;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 0;
  transition: all .2s;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 10px 30px;
}

.credit__num--fw {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.credit-time,
.credit-pcent {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.credit-advances {
  margin-left: 40px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  border-top: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.credit-advances__list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.credit__list-item {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.credit-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  background: #ddd;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 45px;
  height: 12px;
  margin-left: -22.5px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background .2s;
}

.credit:hover .credit-toggle {
  background: #0e86d6;
}

.credit-toggle--circle {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  transition: background .2s;
}

.credit-toggle--circle:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -10px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  transition: background .2s;
}

.credit-toggle--circle:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -10px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  transition: background .2s;
}

.credit-advances {
  display: none;
}

.credit-advances.opened {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="credit" onclick="show_advances()">
  <div class="credit-wrap">
    <div class="credit__logo">
      <img src="img/credit-logo.png" alt="" width="112px">
    </div>
    <div class="credit__sum">
      <p class="credit__title">CreditStar</p>
      <p class="credit__num">30 000 ₽</p>
      <span class="credit__name">Сумма</span>
    </div>
    <div class="credit-time">
      <p class="credit__num">15 минут</p>
      <span class="credit__name">Время</span>
    </div>
    <div class="credit-pcent">
      <p class="credit__num credit__num--fw">1.5% в день</p>
      <span class="credit__name">Процент</span>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="credit__more-btn">Подробнее</a>
  </div>

  <div class="credit-advances">
    <ul class="credit-advances__list">
      <li class="credit__list-item">Сумма займа от 1 000 до 30 000 рублей</li>
      <li class="credit__list-item">Срок от 7 до 30 дней</li>
      <li class="credit__list-item">Процентная ставка 1.5% в день</li>
      <li class="credit__list-item">Выдача на банковкую карту</li>
      <li class="credit__list-item">Нужен только паспорт</li>
      <li class="credit__list-item">Гражданам РФ с 18 лет</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="credit-toggle" onclick="show_advances()">
    <div class="credit-toggle--circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: область таргета у кнопки внизу поломалась, работает через раз и помоему постоянно в рандомной области.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513, уже вижу что что-то не то...

Answer (score 0):

```js
var show_filter_list = function(obj) {
  obj.classList.toggle("active");
  console.log(obj.nextElementSibling)


  panel = obj.nextElementSibling;
  panel.classList.toggle("opened");
}

var show_b = function(obj) {
  obj.classList.toggle("active");

  panel = obj.previousElementSibling;
  panel.classList.toggle("opened");
}

var show_a = function(obj) {
  obj.classList.toggle("active");

  panel = obj.nextElementSibling;
  panel.classList.toggle("opened");
}
```

```css
.credit {
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  max-width: 922px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: relative;
}

.credit-wrap {
  padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.credit:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.credit__title {
  color: #2c7bdd;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 38px;
}

.credit__num {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.credit__name {
  color: #9c9898;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.credit__more-btn {
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #0e86d6;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 0;
  transition: all .2s;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 10px 30px;
}

.credit__num--fw {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.credit-time,
.credit-pcent {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.credit-advances {
  margin-left: 40px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  border-top: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.credit-advances__list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.credit__list-item {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.credit-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  background: #ddd;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 45px;
  height: 12px;
  margin-left: -22.5px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background .2s;
}

.credit:hover .credit-toggle {
  background: #0e86d6;
}

.credit-toggle--circle {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  transition: background .2s;
}

.credit-toggle--circle:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -10px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  transition: background .2s;
}

.credit-toggle--circle:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -10px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  transition: background .2s;
}

.credit-advances {
  display: none;
}

.credit-advances.opened {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="credit">
  <div class="credit-wrap" onclick="show_a(this)">
    <div class="credit__logo">
      <img src="img/credit-logo.png" alt="" width="112px">
    </div>
    <div class="credit__sum">
      <p class="credit__title">CreditStar</p>
      <p class="credit__num">30 000 ₽</p>
      <span class="credit__name">Сумма</span>
    </div>
    <div class="credit-time">
      <p class="credit__num">15 минут</p>
      <span class="credit__name">Время</span>
    </div>
    <div class="credit-pcent">
      <p class="credit__num credit__num--fw">1.5% в день</p>
      <span class="credit__name">Процент</span>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="credit__more-btn">Подробнее</a>
  </div>

  <div class="credit-advances">
    <ul class="credit-advances__list">
      <li class="credit__list-item">Сумма займа от 1 000 до 30 000 рублей</li>
      <li class="credit__list-item">Срок от 7 до 30 дней</li>
      <li class="credit__list-item">Процентная ставка 1.5% в день</li>
      <li class="credit__list-item">Выдача на банковкую карту</li>
      <li class="credit__list-item">Нужен только паспорт</li>
      <li class="credit__list-item">Гражданам РФ с 18 лет</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="credit-toggle" onclick="show_b(this)">
    <div class="credit-toggle--circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение с toggle с использованием jq:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.credit').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.credit.active .credit-advances {
    display: block;
}


.credit {
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  max-width: 922px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: relative;
}

.credit-wrap {
  padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.credit:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.credit__title {
  color: #2c7bdd;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 38px;
}

.credit__num {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.credit__name {
  color: #9c9898;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.credit__more-btn {
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #0e86d6;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 0;
  transition: all .2s;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 10px 30px;
}

.credit__num--fw {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.credit-time,
.credit-pcent {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.credit-advances {
  margin-left: 40px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  border-top: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.credit-advances__list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.credit__list-item {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.credit-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  background: #ddd;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 45px;
  height: 12px;
  margin-left: -22.5px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background .2s;
}

.credit:hover .credit-toggle {
  background: #0e86d6;
}

.credit-toggle--circle {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  transition: background .2s;
}

.credit-toggle--circle:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -10px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  transition: background .2s;
}

.credit-toggle--circle:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -10px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  transition: background .2s;
}

.credit-advances {
  display: none;
}

.credit-advances.opened {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="credit">
  <div class="credit-wrap">
    <div class="credit__logo">
      <img src="img/credit-logo.png" alt="" width="112px">
    </div>
    <div class="credit__sum">
      <p class="credit__title">CreditStar</p>
      <p class="credit__num">30 000 ₽</p>
      <span class="credit__name">Сумма</span>
    </div>
    <div class="credit-time">
      <p class="credit__num">15 минут</p>
      <span class="credit__name">Время</span>
    </div>
    <div class="credit-pcent">
      <p class="credit__num credit__num--fw">1.5% в день</p>
      <span class="credit__name">Процент</span>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="credit__more-btn">Подробнее</a>
  </div>

  <div class="credit-advances">
    <ul class="credit-advances__list">
      <li class="credit__list-item">Сумма займа от 1 000 до 30 000 рублей</li>
      <li class="credit__list-item">Срок от 7 до 30 дней</li>
      <li class="credit__list-item">Процентная ставка 1.5% в день</li>
      <li class="credit__list-item">Выдача на банковкую карту</li>
      <li class="credit__list-item">Нужен только паспорт</li>
      <li class="credit__list-item">Гражданам РФ с 18 лет</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="credit-toggle">
    <div class="credit-toggle--circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```